# FieldBridge for Timestamp in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, search, annotations, hibernate-search

What is the FieldBridge for timestamp in HIbernate Search?

@Field

public java.sql.Timestamp approvedDate;

Comment: Didn't understand question. What action you try to perform and what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the [BridgeFactory source code](http://viewvc.jboss.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/hibernate/search/trunk/src/java/org/hibernate/search/bridge/BridgeFactory.java?revision=15567&view=markup&pathrev=15567), it seems there is no default FieldBridge for timestamps.

I think you should provide your own custom FieldBridge.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, here is what I use:

```
@Field(index=Index.UN_TOKENIZED)
@DateBridge(resolution=Resolution.MILLISECOND)
public Timestamp getCreated(){
  return super.getCreated();
}
```

and the good thing it is working fine :)